# React Native Tab Navigator - Swipe Event

Tags: android, react-native, tabnavigator

I am working with **React Native Tab Navigator**.I am **able to listen Tab Press events** , using below code snippet.

**But is there any way to get Tab Swipe Events?**

```
SecondComponent: {
        screen: UserDetails,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation, navigationOptions }) => ({
            tabBarOnPress: (previousScreen, jumpToIndex) => {
                navigation.navigate('UserDetails', { data: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 });
            },
            tabBarLabel: 'Details',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                <Image
                    source={require('./assets/images/contacticon.png')}
                    style={[styles.icon, { tintColor: tintColor }]}
                />
            )
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The event listener was called `onRequestChangeTab`, but later it was changed `onIndexChange`. You should try that on you **TabNavigator** config. (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/2527)

`onNavigationStateChange` would not work since it's executed every time you navigate, whether it happens inside tabs or stack.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.I tried with both methods ,but it get called too many times.Could you please guide with code snippet/example

Comment: did you find any solution for it? looking to control on swipe event